# How do I install ORAC?

Tags: installation, 12.10, 32-bit

ORAC is a 3D chemical modelling software designed for UNIX OS and I have downloaded the tarball http://www.chim.unifi.it/orac/orac.5_3_3.tags.rel_5.3.3.r1963.tar.gz and extracted it but now I have no idea what to do. The README file included read:

```
Prerequisites:
    * GNU Make
    * GCC 4.3 or higher
    * (possibly) other Fortran 90 compilers

Prerequisites for building the parallel version:
    * MPI (Message Passing Interface) libraries and
      implementation/environment:
      MPICH2    [http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/] 
      -or-
      OPENMPI   [http://www.open-mpi.org/]

    * also see README_PARALLEL in tests/*/

To build ORAC executable program:

  make show         # to list all available compilation targets
  make <target>   

To build a fresh distribution, cleaning all files created by user:

make distro
```

I am running 32 bit 12.10 and I have GNU Make installed and GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make will compile this for you... Basically, you just have to run `make <target>` in the orac.5_3_3.r1963 directory.

First you will need the compilation tool required to build ORAC...

```
remi@host:~/$ sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

More tools and library might be required too, but you will have to check yourself : as the README doesn't say anything about dependancies, try to compile and see if it fail...

Then let's run make; several targets are supported, let choose *default*

```
remi@host:~/orac.5_3_3.r1963$ make default
```

When the compilation is finished you will find an executable `orac_Linux` in `orac.5_3_3.r1963/src/default`